# SQL parameters with if statement vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql

So I am developing an application which is based on deposit and withdrawal money from an account(saving account and checking account). To do that, I've created a database where the values will be recorded with SQL Parameters.

But now I got stuck in one of the parameters `.Add("@descriptionTransaction", SqlDbType.Char).Value = cmdDeposit.Text`, because if I click on Deposit button it will be recorded in descriptionTransaction column as Deposit. In the other hand, if I do the same for the Withdrawal button of course it does not work because the `cmdWithdrawal.Text` is not declared. I should create an if statement whenever the user click on cmdDeposit it will write Deposit or cmdWithdrawal it will write Withdrawal.

This is the code that I am actually using for the sql parameters:

```
    With SqlCmd.Parameters
         .Add("@tpAccount", SqlDbType.Char).Value = cbTpAccount.SelectedItem
         .Add("@dateTransaction", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtDate.Text
         .Add("@descriptionTransaction", SqlDbType.Char).Value = cmdDeposit.Text
         .Add("@amountTransaction", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtWithdrawal.Text
         .Add("@balanceTransaction", SqlDbType.Money).Value = txtBalance.Text
    End With
```

There is any way to make this If statement work?

Answer (score 1):

```
With SqlCmd.Parameters
     .Add("@tpAccount", SqlDbType.Char).Value = cbTipoConta.SelectedItem
     .Add("@dateTransaction", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtDate.Text
     .Add("@descriptionTransaction", SqlDbType.Char).Value = if(cmdDepositar.Text="", cmdWithdrawal.Text, cmdDepositar.Text)
     .Add("@amountTransaction", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtDeposito.Text
     .Add("@balanceTransaction", SqlDbType.Money).Value = txtBalance.Text
End With
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes. It is something like that. Thanks mate

Comment: Actually this is not working, this is always return me "Deposit" instead of "Withdrawal" when it is the case

Comment: @Leprechaun: Your Answer is right but use the IIF function in vb.net for reduce the code.

Comment: @IGottaGo I guess you should use `... = If(string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmdDepositar.Text) ... ` or even `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` to check if there is a text in your box.

Answer (score 0):

```
With SqlCmd.Parameters
     .Add("@tpAccount", SqlDbType.Char).Value = cbTipoConta.SelectedItem
     .Add("@dateTransaction", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtDate.Text
     .Add("@descriptionTransaction", SqlDbType.Char).Value = iif(String.IsNullOrEmpty(cmdDepositar.Text), "", cmdDepositar.Text)
     .Add("@amountTransaction", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtDeposito.Text
     .Add("@balanceTransaction", SqlDbType.Money).Value = txtBalance.Text
End With
```

Try this

Comment: I like that method too. Thanks mate

Comment: This is not the valid VB .NET syntax for conditional operator.

Comment: @IGottaGo: Please use iif() for check the condition for write full If statement.